# Where GKE logs stored in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I can see logs are present in Stack driver Logging. But want to know here it stored (in any container?) Can I apply rotation on it because I need only 3 months data. And where to check how much it cost of storing the logs.

Answer (score 2):

Each and every project has **_Default** and **_Required** [Logs buckets](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#overview), and there is no [cost involve](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#pricing).

> Required

- holds Admin Activity audit logs, System Event audit logs, and Access Transparency logs, and retains them for 400 days. You aren't charged for the logs stored in _Required, and the retention period of the logs stored here cannot be modified. You cannot delete this bucket.

> Default

- holds all other ingested logs in a Google Cloud project except for the logs held in the *_Required bucket*. Standard Cloud Logging pricing applies to these logs. Log entries held in the _Default bucket are retained for 30 days, unless you apply custom retention rules. You can't delete this bucket, but you can disable the _Default log sink that routes logs to this bucket.

To answer your question about GKE pods logs, they are stored in the **_Default** bucket. Until now, there is no cost associated to storing them, but [NOTE](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#pricing) storage costs will apply to all chargeable logs retained **longer than the default retention periods** at the rate of $.01 per GiB per month (or fraction thereof); as of **March 31, 2021**.

Here's the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read?hl=en) for how to read your pod's logs from the GCS bucket:

```
gcloud logging read resource.type="k8s_pod"
```

Comment: Where GKE Pods STDOUT logs stored? And it doesn't involve any cost? What is the life span rotation of logs? I guess it stored in container so we have to pay container cost, isn't it? is there any cost involve in accessing the logs? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, as there is no cost associated in storing (if longer than default retention periods), and also no cost for accessing the logs.

Comment: As you said that GKE STDOUT pods logs are stored in _Default bucket and its retention period is 30 days. But I can still access of logs from stack driver Log Explorer more than 6 months old.

Comment: I see.. but this is not always guaranteed as per this https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#overview

Comment: Even 1 Year old logs are accessible. It doesn't mean I have to pay anything for it, right?